# I am fairly new to python and I want to know if my code will execute the task I described or did I miss anything? how can I fix the picture error?

Tags: python

The program is supposed to take the rows in column [newAssetCode] and compare them to the rows in column ['allAssetCodes'] to then find the assets in [newAssetCode] that already exist in ['allAssetCodes']. The program will then count how many times the assets exist in ['allAssetCodes']. for example if If ['allAssetCodes'] contains 'XYZ','XYZ1', 'XYZ2' it will count that and then add a digit to that count and append that number in a new list creating 'XYZ3'. Then count how many instances of 'XYZ' there are again until they have been correctly numbered. Did I write this code correctly? so that it can perform the task above and how can I fix this error

[image]

Comment: People spraying minuses should explain themselves. OP is new on the site.

Comment: This will happen if Codes.xlsx doesn't exist in your 'Python Projects' directory

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file you are trying to load, Codes.xlsx, is in the same directory as the python script you are running.

Comment: or, provide the full path to where the file is

Comment: Both Codes.xlsx and the script are located in the same directory. How can I provide a full path to where the file?

Comment: You can put it as an argument as you would with a relative path, .e.g. pd.read_excel("C:/example/cwd/mydir/myfile.xlsx") To print the path to your current folder you can write import os print(os.getcwd())